# HP Elite Thunderbolt 3 and Dell XPS 13 in Ubuntu 16.10 problem

Tags: usb-c

I have a 50% functioning setup with HP Thunderbolt 3 dock (ASMedia ASM1042A) on Dell XPS 13 9350 laptop in kubuntu 16.10 (currently upgraded to kernel 4.9). BIOS upgraded to newest available (1.4.13)

The display ports and power supply work without any problem. The external audio port starts to works about 10 minutes after the boot. The USB ports do not function at all. The problem is visible in logs - dmesg is constantly (and forever) displaying:

```
[   33.293363] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 67 using xhci_hcd
[   33.761342] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 68 using xhci_hcd
[   34.229235] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 69 using xhci_hcd
```

running to 127th device and again from 2.

The lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0572:1804 Conexant Systems (Rockwell), Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
05:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
05:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
05:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
06:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 010f (rev 01)
```

Looking forward to some ideas on how to resolve!

Thanks, Bobster

Answer (score 0):

ArchLinux has a nice write-up on the [DEL XPS 13 (9350)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9350)).

Firstly your BIOS was updated 2017-09-28. You'll need to boot with a modern Windows version to install it.

Thunderbolt3 Hotplug support for this port requires a bug fix which landed in kernel version 4.7. It also requires the kernel to be built with CONFIG_PCI_HOTPLUG=y. I just checked Ubuntu Mainline Kernel 4.14.4 and sadly it doesn't appear compiled with this option. Hopefully the **Ubuntu Kernel Team** gets around to adding this configuration option soon.

Starting with Kernel 4.13 Dell allows [Thunderbolt NVM updates over Linux](https://github.com/dell/thunderbolt-nvm-linux). New apps are available to flash the Thunderbolt controller.